# NullPointerException on mocked method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

For the method below:

```
public void parseJSONData(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        if (jsonData == null || jsonData.length() == 0)
            throw new JSONException("Empty JSON string");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("beacons");        

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject item = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            addBeaconData(item); 
        }
    }
```

I wrote the following test method

```
    @Test
        public void testParseJSONData() throws Exception {

            String jsonData="testJson";    
            JSONObject jsonObject = PowerMockito.mock(JSONObject.class);  
            PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withArguments(jsonData).thenReturn(jsonObject);

            JSONArray arr = PowerMockito.mock(JSONArray.class);
            PowerMockito.when(jsonObject.getJSONArray(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(arr);        

            JSONObject item = new JSONObject();    
            PowerMockito.when(arr.length()).thenReturn(1);    
            PowerMockito.when(arr.getJSONObject(0)).thenReturn(item);

            BeaconDataParser jsonParser=PowerMockito.spy(new BeaconDataParser());
            PowerMockito.doNothing().when(jsonParser).addBeaconData(item); 
            jsonParser.parseJSONData(jsonData);
    }
```

The result is a null pointer exception at the line with the for loop. What could be the reason for the failure. The length method of the arr object is mocked. 
There are 2 class annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({JSONArray.class,JSONObject.class})
```

Comment: This means that `arr` was null. This means that `obj.getJSONArray(obj)` was not mocked and returned null. By the way this line doesn't look ok, and I am surprised that it compiles, I though the only legal parameter for `getJSONArray` is `String`, not another `JSONObject`.

Comment: PowerMockit is very likely not mocking anything. Do you have proper `@RunWith` and `@PrepareForTest` annotations at your test class?

Comment: There was a typo. I fixed it. I have 2 annotations

Comment: please add full body of the for loop in which the error occures

Comment: There was another method call. The NullPointerException is for arr.length().

Comment: @user1802439 I am not exactly sure how power mock works and how you are trying to mock an object `obj` which is created in your code. Anyway, why don't you just pass a json string that you want to test? What's the point of mocking here?

Answer (score 1):

In your method is:

```
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray(obj);
```

But in your test is:

```
PowerMockito.when(jsonObject.getJSONArray(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(arr);
```

You expexct to invoke getJSONArray(with any String), but actually you invoke it with JSONObject

This is the problem of NPE, but what should `obj.getJSONArray(obj)` do? Is this correct? It looks like you should use some key for your data, not the object on which you invoke it.

probably the error is in line:

```
 JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray(obj);
```

What key you expect here? it should be:

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("key for your array");
```

Comment: There was a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding Jaroslaw in the comments, there is absolutely no reason to get a mocking framework involved in JSON parsing. JSON is well-specified and well-tested, and will not be the source of bugs.

Instead, pass in a variety of beacon JSON strings to your method, one per test, and spy on calls to addBeaconData if necessary. The best test of all, though, will simply test that calls to parseJSONData will result in the unmocked BeaconDataParser *state* you expect.

Comment: I get your point. I just want to understand why only one of the two mocked objects behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the arr.length() is called second time, try:

```
public void parseJSONData(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        if (jsonData == null || jsonData.length() == 0)
            throw new JSONException("Empty JSON string");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("beacons");        
        int size = arr.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            JSONObject item = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            addBeaconData(item); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are mocking a method local instantiation, You have to add the classname in **prepareForTest** that is calling that constructor.
Here **BeaconDataParser** is the class which is creating the **JSONObject** with new operator.

**Below are other observations:**

> 1) No need to add JSONArray.class, JSONObject.class in prepareForTest as they are normal java objects only. 
>   2) JSONObject has multiple overloaded constructors, So you need to specify the parameter type when mocking with whenNew.

**Your test class should be like this.**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ BeaconDataParser.class })
public class BeaconDataParserTest {

 @Test
 public void testParseJSONData() throws Exception {

    String jsonData = "testJson";
    JSONObject jsonObject = PowerMockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withParameterTypes(String.class). withArguments(jsonData)
            .thenReturn(jsonObject);

    JSONArray arr = PowerMockito.mock(JSONArray.class);
    PowerMockito.when(jsonObject.getJSONArray(Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(arr);

    JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
    PowerMockito.when(arr.length()).thenReturn(1);
    PowerMockito.when(arr.getJSONObject(0)).thenReturn(item);

    BeaconDataParser jsonParser = PowerMockito.spy(new BeaconDataParser());
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(jsonParser).addBeaconData(item);
    jsonParser.parseJSONData(jsonData);
 }

}
```